# Object not behaving as reference

Tags: php

In PHP, I assume that every object is reference, however in this code;

```
  /**
 * adds a master object which affects browse and insert operations
 *
 * @param \bk\dataset\master|string $cursor            
 * @param Array $fields            
 */
function SetMasterCursor ($cursor, $fields)
{
    if (is_object($cursor)) {
        $this->master = & $cursor; /** !!!!!! **/
    } elseif (is_string($cursor)) {
        $this->master = \bk\dataset\master::instance($cursor, null, $this->GetModuleName());
    }
    $this->_masterfld = $fields;
}
```

I need to force PHP to use reference with `&` operator (`$this->master = & $cursor`). If I do not use the operator, it is acting strangely. It is calling constructor of cursor class. So obviously it is not just copying reference. I thought, from PHP5 on `$object1 = $object2` and `$object1 = & $object2` are the same, it is just different for other types (string etc.). I got a feeling that my assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is explained into detail here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

There is a difference of passing an object by **"default"** or by **"reference"**.
By default objects are passed by copying the identifier of the object.

I think the following code (of the above page) makes it clear:

```
<?php
class Foo {
  private static $used;
  private $id;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->id = self::$used++;
  }
  public function __clone() {
    $this->id = self::$used++;
  }
}

$a = new Foo; // $a is a pointer pointing to Foo object 0
$b = $a; // $b is a pointer pointing to Foo object 0, however, $b is a copy of $a
$c = &$a; // $c and $a are now references of a pointer pointing to Foo object 0
$a = new Foo; // $a and $c are now references of a pointer pointing to Foo object 1, $b is still a pointer pointing to Foo object 0
```

(It is rather ugly if you ask me, but that is how it is ;) ).

Comment: the behaviour in your example is just what I expected. the problem in my example is  $b = $a (assignment) causes constructor call. '$this->master = $cursor' calls the constructor of $cursor class. while '$this->master = & $cursor' does not.

Comment: It is indeed weird that it calls the contructor, could you provide a minimal working example such I can test it myself? My answer points out though that even for objects the assignment is different then by reference, since it is copying the pointer and not creating an "alias".

Comment: I am accepting this as correct answer, because it is just PHP behaves. I stucked at calling the constructor twice during debugging. But I cannot replicate it. May be some other code was causing this. I will return back to here when I can replicate. Anyway, this answer cleared things about references, cloning etc. Thanks.